# Granting access to anything on a path in the Java policy file

Tags: java, security, jruby, policy

I'm dealing with a badly-behaved library (JRuby) which tries to read the entire universe and then fails to deal with the `SecurityException` as well, thus fails to start up at all.

```
Caused by: org.jruby.exceptions.RaiseException: (LoadError) library `java' could not be loaded: java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.io.FilePermission" "/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/ant-javafx.jar" "read")
```

I don't mind JRuby (or any other library, for that matter) reading the entire universe, though, so I am trying to figure out how to add this to the grants. This jar file turns out to be on the java.class.path, but I can't figure out the rule to grant the permission.

Taking examples from other policy files I have seen in the past, I have been trying things like this:

```
grant {
    permission java.io.FilePermission "${{java.class.path}}", "read, execute";
    permission java.io.FilePermission "${{java.class.path}}/-", "read, execute";
};
```

But it makes no difference whatsoever, so I suspect this `${{...}}` syntax only works for the codeBase.

Is there a way to do it for file permissions as well?

Comment: It doesn’t help you as the libraries contained in the JDK/JRE are not contained in the class path. You might check out `java.ext.dirs` instead. Or give access to the entire `java.ext.dirs`. Some JREs support the non-standard property `sun.boot.class.path`. But I never used the `${…}` thing in a policy file though.

Comment: You're half right. *Some* of the libraries are not contained in the class path (e.g. the main class library.) Those ones are not a problem - my policy file just allows reading from anything inside ${java.home}. But libraries like ant-javafx.jar are definitely on java.class.path and I'm not the one putting them there. And because they live in jdk/lib instead of jre/lib, they aren't inside ${java.home}. But they are on ${java.class.path}, which is why I want to know whether there is a way to make use of that. And actually, once I have a way to do that, I can make it use ${java.ext.dirs} too.

Comment: Oh, I see. I couldn’t tell jre/lib and jdk/lib apart given your MacOS-specific path. As far as I can see, all `${propertyname}` expansions work, including `${java.class.path}`. But the result of the expansion doesn’t work because the property `java.class.path` expands to a search path containing multiple files and `java.io.FilePermission` doesn’t support such a multi-file path. The syntax with the double curly brace is a [completely different thing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/PolicyFiles.html#GeneralExp) and doesn’t help here.